# Event Date in Calendar sets on day earlier after saving

Tags: objective-c, ios6, calendar, nsdate, ekevent

I am new with EKEventKit and I am trying to create an event in calendar using EKEvent. It works fine but after saving the event when I check again the event date it gets one day earlier.

I am writing my code here with output. Please have a look

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc]init];
    [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];

        // set Event Title and Notes
        event.title = @"My New Event";
        event.notes = @"New event notes are added by azeem";

        // set Event Start and End date here
        NSLog(@"before saving Date: %@",[NSDate date]);
        event.startDate = [NSDate date];
        event.endDate =[NSDate date];

        // set Evet other Properties here
        event.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
        event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        event.allDay = YES;

        [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
        NSLog(@"After saving Date: %@",event.startDate);
```

`OUTPUT ::`

```
Before Saving Date : 2013-04-10 08:00:40 +0000
After Saving Date:   2013-04-09 00:00:00 +0000
```

We can see here that there is 1 Day before. but they should be same.

I hope I am very much clear with my question, but still if any question, you can ask me.

thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Why you nullify timezone? If your application is for different countries, than you shoudn't do that.

```
event.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

And yes printed NSDate differs from date that will be added to EvencCalendar - it's ok(because of GMT +x etc.). Added date will be equal to your start date.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem... 
It seems indeed weird that [NSDate date] would return a date 1 day earlier.
Are you sure it is not the event.startDate and event.endDate that get change?
I got your describe behaviour with the following logs:

```
event.startDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"before saving Date: %@",event.startDate);
event.endDate =[NSDate date];

// set Evet other Properties here
event.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:10];
event.calendar = [eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
event.allDay = YES;

[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
NSLog(@"After saving Date: %@",event.startDate);
```

This is due to the set of the timeZone. 
I would recommend to use [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] or [NSTimeZone localTimeZone] to adjust to your user settings, and then let the magic happen :-) Your event date will be set to the current date according to your user point of view.

Cheers,